Schematics review request: ESP32+Tasmota based multifunctional board with PWM and 12v IO
I'm pretty lame in creating PCB's and now I'm trying to create a ESP32-based brushed motor controller for the sailing boat engine bay ventilation.
My target is to have:
4x fwd / reverse (full bridge) PWM's to control 12V*15A exhaust fans.
4x 12-24V digital inputs that need to trigger GPIO up
4x 12-24V switchable output that connects / disconnects + (that's a requirement, cause - is always on to the devices)
4x I2C expansion JST connector
4x buttons to control the device
4x status LED's
Implementation is made:

Using DRV8701 driver with MCACD55N04YHE3 FET's
TCMT4606 optocouplers triggered by FFB5551
FQP27P07 triggered by FFB2222A
Expanded GPIO using MCP23017

Please, help me to review the schematics. I'm very new to this and that's my first self-designed PCB so I'm afraid of missing something / wrong values for passives or wrong design. Thank you!
UPD:

Fixed grounds/power in
Fixed wrong DVR8701 MOSFET connections (mind the arrows directions! Icon in the reference design are mirrored for half of the bridge!)




this kind of reviews are complex and not something that can be done quickly. It's something you need experience in and really take your time to do, check the pins the operation, the intended operation, current limits.. In short, hours of work. I suppose you could ask some of the users here to do it, but this kind of thing is usually charged and based on my experience it will be in thousands or at least hundreds of $.

If you have some specific questions though we would love to help.

Did you calculate the power loss in RN1?

Convention is that ground points down and positive power is up.  Consider using a multi-part symbol for the resistor networks so that the schematic reads easier. For us old-timers, that schematic does not read well and really only serves to show interconnections rather than communicate how the circuit works.  The optos are a waste of time - they don’t give you any protection or isolation as drawn.

@Jens Nope, my bad. I considered that's 1kOhm here is a pull-up resistor, no? Keeping FET closed. So what to look at? Zero Gate Voltage Drain Current?

@Kartman Thank you! I've updated the styling and schematics. Regarding the optos - it the situation with the non-isolated ground, as I do understand, no need to use them at all? What's the better approach here?

Your MOSFETs for the motors are still wired the wrong way, please compare it to the examples in the datasheet of the DRV8701

@HansmitmFlammenwerfer Thank you! I've fixed it. I didn't pointed that in the reference designed they used mirrored FET symbols for the prettier view.

@Kartman I've remade 3.3-24V input without optocouplers. But keeping the idea using FFB5551 to give a larger range of the input voltage.

@KirErmakov If RN1 is a typical quad resistor device 144 mW per resistor at 12 V is too much. They are not all 4 under load at the same time, but the device may fail early.

@Jens - I planned to use http://www.vishay.com/docs/31509/csc.pdf
It's marked as 0.25w. But I believe your concern here is valuable, - I've updated it to https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/4100R-776985.pdf, in has near 2w per resistor.
